# Silverlight 4 Out of Browser error

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, sqlmembershipprovider

Using the Silverlight 4 WCF RIA services works just fine via web page.  After installing it as an Out Of Browser application, there is a blank screen then an error comes up saying "Load operation failed for query 'GetUser'. The HTTP request to 'http://reports.mywebsite.com/Reports/ClientBin/Reports-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/GetUser' has exceed the allotted timeout..."  Using the SqlMembershipProvider with userid/password in the database connection string - using Forms Authenication.

Clicking 'OK' and then the login screen comes up and everything's normal thereafter.

Kinda odd that the timeout happened and then everything's fine.  What can I do to prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your RootVisual not being set to something.  See my post here that addresses this issue:

http://blog.virtual-olympus.com/blog/post/2011/04/10/Silverlight-4-Out-of-Browser%E2%80%93Windows-Authentication-Timeout.aspx